# How does passing parameters through functions work in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, cs50

I'm relatively new to Python and I was watching the CS50P lectures and didn't grasp how passing parameters worked.

```
def main():
    x = int(input("what's x?"))
    if is_even(x):
        print('EVEN NUMBER')
    else:
        print('ODD NUMBER')


def is_even(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

main()
```

For example, why can't I write `is_even(x)` instead of `is_even(n)`. Also, how do the boolean values get returned to my main function? I know the code below works, I just don't understand how the information moves from one function back to another.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You can name the function parameter whatever you like. It has nothing to do with the variable that you use when calling it, since you can call the function from different places with different argument variables. The parameter is just a local variable that's used to refer to the argument that was passed.

Comment: Adding to @Barmar's comment, you can name the variables whatever you want, _**but you have to be consistent**_. For example, you input `x` in `main()`, so need to call the function with `is_even(x)`. Then your function definition has `def is_even(n)`, so you need to use `n` in the function. The returned value is on the return statement line (`return True` or `return False`). If `return` is blank, nothing is returned to the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter set when defining a is really a placeholder if you understand. Take your line of code for example.

```
def main():
    x = int(input("what's x?"))
    if is_even(x):
        print('EVEN NUMBER')
    else:
        print('ODD NUMBER')


def is_even(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

main()
```

Using your code, when you type n inside of the parenthesis when you define the function `is_even`,  n is really a placeholder. So later when you execute `is_even` as shown in `if is_even(x):` what happening is it is taking the variable x as shown and substituting it wherever you put the placeholder n. Hopefully, this clarifies your question. Barmar and kcw78 are correct however I put it in a more easy-to-understand format. I couldn't comment on this due to my reputation.